# javafx nullpointer exception when I'm setting onclose request in controller

Tags: java, javafx

Мне нужно установить метод который срабатывал бы при нажатии на (Х) закрытия окна, но получаю nullpointer облазил много форумов ничего толком не нашел. Что я делаю не так?
как правильно установить ивэнт на закрытие окна, если для его открытия я меняю сцену на стэйдже.

Метод который открывает окно

```
@FXML
    private void addTovarMenuItemAction() throws IOException {
        Stage stage = (Stage) filterButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FXMLmarkup/addTovar.fxml"));
        Parent root1 = null;
        root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        stage = new Stage();
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.setTitle("Booking Magazine");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));

        stage.show();
    }
```

Код в Контроллере

```
 @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        createSklad();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.getScene().getWindow().setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Closed");
            }
        });
```

Полный лог ошибки

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=57243:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Назар\IdeaProjects\Booking Magazine\out\production\Booking Magazine;C:\Users\Назар\IdeaProjects\Booking Magazine\mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar" sample.Main
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%80/IdeaProjects/Booking%20Magazine/out/production/Booking%20Magazine/FXMLmarkup/addTovar.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at sample.Controller.addTovarMenuItemAction(Controller.java:287)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.addTovarConrol.initialize(addTovarConrol.java:54)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 56 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Прикрипите полный текст ошибки

Comment: @Komdosh прикрепил.

Comment: Мне кажется `/FXMLmarkup/addTovar.fxml` не открывается, он точно есть в пути  `C:/Users/Назар/IdeaProjects/Booking Magazine/out/production/Booking Magazine/FXMLmarkup/addTovar.fxml`? Если нет, то ищите где он должен быть, видимо он не в resource.

Comment: @Komdosh он точно там есть, так кака я только уберу метод из кода в контроллере, который есть выше то всё отлично работает

Answer (score 1):

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    createSklad();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.getScene()...
```

Вот в этом месте у вас NPE. У только что созданного `Stage` сцены нет. Установите соответствующую/пустую сцену и должно заработать.